# How do I keep a reference when using nested views in AngularJS?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular-ui-router

I have 4 pages. 
2 pages in English and 2 pages in French.

Here are the 4 options : 
EN > Page1 - Content: **Computer** 
EN > Page2 - Content: **Keyboard**

FR > Page1 - Content: **Ordinateur** 
FR > Page2 - Content: **Clavier**

How do switch a nested view for its equivalent?

I have put together a plnkr. 
https://embed.plnkr.co/SZPp0C8guVeTtcLeWJ3T/

Any help is appreciated! Thanks!

---

> Expected Behaviour. When I click on "Francais", say I am on `/en/page1/`, I want it to properly re-route to, in this case, `/fr/page1`.

[image: expected behavior]

---

> Actual Behaviour. When I click on "Francais", say I am on `/en/page1/`, it re-routes me to `/fr` and I don't know how to approach the problem at hand.

[image: actual behavior]

Comment: do you want it to go to `Page1` for each language when you click the language link?  you probably don't ever want to go to `/en` or `/fr`, you always want to go to `/en/page1` or `/fr/page1`.....

Comment: Yup! I never want to end up on the first level page. I always want the language anchor to bring me to `/en/*` or `/fr/*`

Comment: right, then you never want to use `ui-sref="english"`, for example, because it's mapped to the `/en` url.  If your goal is only to go to page1, then fix the `ui-sref` items.  If your goal is to remember what page they were on and go to that one, then you'll still have to fix the `ui-sref`, but it will be based on a property that saves the page number.

Comment: you probably want the `engilsh` state to be `abstract`.

Comment: @Claies I know what you mean but I just don't know how to execute it haha. Could you maybe modify my plnkr and show me? I'm a visual learner :)

Comment: I messed with this a bit more and I'm not really sure how to do this correctly in ui-router.  I'll do a bit more research but maybe someone more familiar with nested routes can give you a better idea.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I forked a new plunker and updated it. The challenge was to watch the scope of the route provider to see what prior values existed. Looking at the current state and name you can conditionally control in the controller which view is persisted. to do this I created a new function:

```
  //evaluate routes
  let checkRouteValues = (oldVal, newVal)=>{
    $scope.vm.message1 = oldVal;
    $scope.vm.message2 = newVal;

    //first check to see if language has changed
    if(newVal === 'english'&& oldVal ==='francais.page1'){
     $state.go('english.page1');
    }else if(newVal === 'english' && oldVal ==='francais.page2'){
         $state.go('english.page2')
    }else if(newVal ==='francais' && oldVal === 'english.page1' ){
        $state.go('francais.page1');
    }else if (newVal ==='francais' && oldVal === 'english.page2' ){
      $state.go('francais.page2');
    }
  }
```

Then added a watch to see when the state changed:

```
 //added a watch to monitor the current state
  $scope.currState =$state;
  $scope.$watch('currState.current.name', function (newValue, oldValue){

     checkRouteValues(oldValue, newValue)
  });
```

The function checkRouteValues() monitors the new and old values and then sets the state based upon the condition. 
*caveat: I think this solution works for something small scale like this navigation here however if you had multiple pages I would look to go a different route.

[updated plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/kp6pYgwuUbU7I5hkVQOc?p=preview)

I did add some logging in the html so you could see the values change
I did change the name of the app from theApp to app so be careful if you cpoy paste.

I did use arrow functions in the code if you don't like arrow functions you can convert it back to

```
let checkRouteValues = function(oldVal, newVal){...}
```

I also used `let` declaration vs. `var` to isolate variable scope but you can use var as if you prefer.

And finally with my changes change the route english, page one, is always the default loaded route when your app starts but this should give you enough to get you going.

Comment: Thank you so much @rlcrews! You gave me a working example, a full explanation on everything you did in the code, pointed out a caveat, suggested a best practice alternative and a comparison on why you did something one way versus another. Thanks to you, my problem was solve and I managed to implement your solution into my project. You're a god!